# Laravel pagination render() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.1

I have a controller que find the products and return to view .
Current I'm trying make the pagination and I'm using the following code :

```
return $this->queryProductsAvailable()
                ->where('fornecedores.plano_id', $plano)
                ->select('produtos.*')
                ->paginate( $limit );
```

function queryProductsAvailabe:

```
private function queryProductsAvailable()
{   
   return Products::join('fornecedores', 'fornecedores.id', '=' ,'produtos.fornecedor_id')
                        ->where( 'fornecedores.ativo', '1')
                        ->where( 'produtos.moderacao', 'P' )
                        ->where( 'produtos.ativo' , '1' )  
                        ->where( 'produtos.preco_min', '>', 0 )
                        ->select( 'produtos.*');                   
}
```

To view I'm return the following:

```
return view('Catalogo.index', 
                    [ 
                        'products' => $products
                    ] 
                );
```

But when I run the method `$products->render()` nothing happens.
No errors, no messages... 
if I run `$products->total()` is returned the value 0 
if I run `$products->nextPageUrl()` nothing happens

The same variable used to access this methods is used for the loop and print of products and the foreach works fine.

if I access the url with `/?page=2` the pagination works, but not render list of pages.

Any idea?

**---- Edite  ----**

The code works as follows:

In my site there are plans (plans 5 levels) that will make the products are listed before the other, then the search for the product I do the following:

In the first search I seek 30 level products 5 if the level 5 does not have 30 products I check how many products brought to query, I reduce the 30 and seek more product in the plan 4 to complete the 30 products and so on.

In this process, when we decrease a plan I use the push methodo to add the collection and whenever there is the decrease in the plan, the paginate limit is also being changed ...

So I have two points that may be causing this problem, the first is the push method and the second in the act of reducing the plan and seek more products with a different paginate the first one was 30.

Other than that my query also search products randomly, I believe that I need to develop my own paginate to meet all my requirements ...

Thank you all

Comment: How many results are you expecting?  `render()` won't do anything if you have less than the number of results you are paginating.

Comment: hi @user3158900. 
My paginate receive the value 30 and the variable show 30 products. 
in the database exists 500 products.

Answer (score 0):

The `paginate()` method ill only add limit and offset in your query. In order to show the results, you will need to return the view instead:

```
$products = $this->queryProductsAvailable()
                ->where('fornecedores.plano_id', $plano)
                ->select('produtos.*')
                ->paginate( $limit );

return view('Catalogo.index', 
                    [ 
                        'products' => $products
                    ] 
                );
```

Comment: I'm already returning this variable... 
But the method ->render(), ->total() is empty. 

I can use the variable to loop and insert the products in html, but when trying to create the pagination list , nothing happens.

Comment: I didn't understood that since in the example you given you don't assign the `$results` variable and return the result of the query instead. What happens if you change paginate with `get()`. BTW, it is `{!! $products->links() !!}` that displays the pagination links.

Comment: It's `render()` in 5.1, `links()` in 5.2.

Comment: php artisan --version
Laravel Framework version 5.1.34 (LTS)

Comment: @BeS   
Are you suggesting that I use get instead of paginate ?

But pagination will not go to work? (Although no longer be working )

Comment: I suggested to use `get()` to see if the problem is in your query. If you don't obtain records with `get()` then it is not a problem with the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your view to print the pagination:

```
{!! $products !!}}
```

It won't show if you have items equal to or less than the limit you have passed to the `paginate($limit)` function

Answer (score 0):

I would do those things:

- Check in your view with firebug or chrome devtools if the html is rendered;
- Check if you're using `{!! $products->render() !!}` in your view;
- Check with dd/var_dump/print_r the results of your query. Replace `->paginate(...)` with `->get()` and see if your query us returnig the correct values.

`return $this->queryProductsAvailable()
                ->where('fornecedores.plano_id', $plano)
                ->select('produtos.*')
                ->get( $limit )`

Try those and come back with your results. I think you are doing somenthing wrong with your query.

- Finally, check storage/logs/laravel.log for any information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! 

I think the problem is in a loop that verify the var $products contain 30 items. 

The loop is  complex to explain but in the loop i use the method ->push (for add in collection the missing itens ) and beyond that the value for paginte is changed during the loop when the first search not get the products limit .

I'm thinking in create my own paging because of the questions above..

Comment: try to use \DB::enableQueryLog() before you query and \DB::getQueryLog() after your query. You can check if your SQL is right. If you can't paginate using SQL, you need to paginate in a different way. But of course, it's a dummy way, because you will fetch all results and only print a few.

Answer (score 0):

Paginate returns a LengthAwarePaginator Object, not a Collection. This might cause the problem.